# What is this runtime error when I run my project?

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface

Using Eclipse Photon, importing a project created elsewhere. There are no errors in the edit window when I load the source code.

I get this error when I click Run:
[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myPackage/Bookstore has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I reconfigured the build path to use my Workspace default JRE, which is 1.8.0_181, and I deleted the bin folder but the error persists.

Comment: That exception message in the background is probably more informative. What does it say?

Comment: [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface): If a library in the Java Build Path uses a native library, make sure the location is correctly specified and matches the JRE used (both either 32 or 64 bit) .

Comment: The UnsupportedClassVersionError says somewhere in your project there's code compiled with Java 10 (class file version 54.0) which your Java 8 runtime can't use (class file version 52.0) Maybe some 3rd party jar. Don't know how that fits with the JNI message, however

Answer (score 0):

I was selecting the Workspace Default JRE : that didn't fix the problem. I tried selecting the Execution Environment JRE and that worked. Here are the steps. It's Eclipse Photon but that should be similar to other recent versions. Here's a video that illustrates the steps: https://youtu.be/IE2B2e90kCs

Open Eclipse, verify your project is loaded in the Project Explorer

Right-click on the project in Project Explorer

Select Build Path

Select Configure Build Path

Click on Libraries Tab

If there is a system library, remove it

Click on the Add Library Button

Select JRE System Library

Click Next

Under System Library: Select "Execution Environment"

Click Finish

Click Apply and Close